# Master volume keeps changing, how can I find out what causes this?

Tags: debian, volume

The master volume keeps changing while I'm listening on youtube music in the browser. The OS is Debian Jessie. I adjusted the volume in the GUI and using the terminal (with "amixer set Master 40%") and it later changed repeatedly regardless the way I've changed it previously. There are no other applications running besides the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If pulse audio is the default and applications are changing it, you may need to fix that. Check these two config files for "flat-volumes"

```
/etc/pulse/daemon.conf 

~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
```

If it exists and is not flat-volumes=no, change it to be no. This *may* solve the issue. I would suggest adding more info...does the volume change when you reboot?, etc

Comment: The problem persists after reboot. I did not know what other information was relevant and didn't want to fill the question with useless clutter. I've changed the "/etc/pulse/daemon.conf" file by setting "flat-volumes" from "yes" to "no". There was no "~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf" file. Thank you so much for your answer. I would like to give it some time before marking it as correct, since the issue manifests intermittently.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to be the answer. After all this time, the problem showed up again, despite having `flat-volumes=no` in `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf` and `vim /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. The volume gets muted after a random time interval (usually a few seconds) after I change it back to what I want it to be.